# Determining units in a cone and plate flow system

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, rotation, biology

I am building a cone and plate system as depicted in **Figure B** below. My goal is to solve for the appropriate rotational speed, ω, given the following parameters:

τ - 15 dynes/cm^2

μ - 0.9 centipoise (cP)

θ - 5 degrees

ω - 83.3 sec^-1 (Hz)

Literature I've read repeatedly references this equation for the cone and plate system, though does not define units or show calculations. Am I using the correct units for each parameter, is there a good reference to verify?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to be sure that your units are consistent. For most of us this means using the SI units because as long as you give everything in SI you can be confident your calculation is correct. That would mean giving the stress in Newtons per square metre and the viscosity in Pascal seconds.

However in many applications other units are used because they are more convenient, and in particular in rheology it's common to use the [centimetre-gram-second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units) system. In this system shear stress has the units of [dynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyne) per square centimetre, and viscosity has the units of [Poise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poise).

So your units are fine as they are, though remember to use the viscosity in poise not centipoise. The angular velocity has the units $s^{-1}$, which is fine, and the angle is dimensionless.